# Проблема при работе БД с IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, iis

Опубликовал свой проект в IIS. При работе с БД выдаёт следующую ошибку: "Не удается открыть базу данных "RefsDB", запрашиваемую именем входа. Не удалось выполнить вход. При входе в систему пользователя "IIS APPPOOL\APIReference" произошла ошибка."

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать или алгоритм решения данной проблемы.

P.S. БД - MSSQL. Проект - ASP.NET.

Comment: Если у вас в строке соединения не указан юзер и пароль,  значит сайт ломится в базу от имени пользователя, от которого работает пул приложений. Либо дайте этому юзеру права в бд, либо запускаете пул приложений от другого юзера, у которого уже есть доступ в базу.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка "Не удается открыть базу данных X запрашиваемую именем входа Y" означает, что пользователя на сервер пустило, но базы с таким именем на сервере не оказалось.

Создайте базу с таким именем, или перенесите на сервер готовую базу с дев машины.